# How do I keep my pages secure where only those who have been authenticated can access them?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I set up an authentication form on my web app but I can still access all the other pages. How do I prevent myself from accessing the pages until I'm authenticated?

I created an interface so that I can use Login method that will take a username and password and return true or false if there is a successful bind.

**Interface**

```
using System;
using HSLogApp.Classes;

namespace HSLogApp.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAuthService
    {
        bool Login(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

I created a class that inherits the interface. The connections is made in the constructor and the Login method is used to receive the username and password.

**Authentication Class**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using HSLogApp.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

namespace HSLogApp.Classes
{
    class LdapAuthenticationService : IAuthService
    {
        private const string MemberOfAttribute = "memberOf";
        private const string DisplayNameAttribute = "displayName";
        private const string SAMAccountNameAttribute = "sAMAccountName";

        private readonly LdapConfig _config;
        private readonly LdapConnection connection;

        public LdapAuthenticationService(IOptions<LdapConfig> config)
        {
            _config = config.Value;
            connection = new LdapConnection
            {
                SecureSocketLayer = true
            };

            try
            {
                connection.Connect(_config.Url, _config.Port);
                // _connection.Bind(username, password);

            }
            catch (LdapException lex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CONNECTION ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine("DETAILS - " + lex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public bool Login(string Username, string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Bind(Username, Password);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT
**View:**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<div class="box-header">
    <h2>Log In</h2>
</div>
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <br />
    <input type="email" id="Username" asp-for="Username" class="form-control">
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="Password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control">
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    <br />
</form>
<a href="#"><p class="small">Forgot your password?</p></a>

<br>
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p class="alert alert-success">
        You are successfully authenticated.
    </p>
}
```

**View Code Behind**
Showing how I check the authentication.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            bool user = _authService.Login(Username, Password);
            if (user)
            {
                Result = true;

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Username)
                };

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                    authProperties);

                    return RedirectToPage("/hslogs/index");
            }
            else
            {
                Result = false;
                return RedirectToPage();
            }
        }
```

I hope this is all you need. Let me know if I need to post more code/information for you to understand my situation.

Comment: How are you checking if the user is logged in before displaying the page? Post the view please.

Comment: I added the code behind to the view to show you how I check if the user is logged in. I hope it helps. @BillRuhl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `[Authorize]` to the top of the controller below the namespace right above `public class IndexModel: PageModel`.

It looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class IndexModel: PageModel
{
    ...
{
```